# jQuery each array using from single attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I would like to know how can I make this work.

I have the following problem:

I have an element in HTML with rel="" attribute which includes product ids by which I display data from Json file.

```
<a href="#" class="openProducts" rel="526231, 487139, 528401, 521564">Open data</a>
```

And I would like to get this rel="" attr with jQuery and use it as array for each function.

My code right now is this:

```
var getProducts = jQuery('.openProducts').attr('rel');
$.each(getProducts, function(index, value) {
...
```

If I use this code it works:

```
var getProducts = [ '526231',' 487139', '528401', '521564' ];
$.each(getProducts, function(index, value) {
...
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) - a regex is used because you don't want the space after `,`

```
var getProducts = jQuery('.openProducts').attr('rel').split(/,\s*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var getProducts = jQuery('.openProducts').attr('rel').split(",");
$.each(getProducts, function(index, value) {
    console.log($.trim(value))
 });
```